# Apache2 process stuck at 100% cpu, CLOSE_WAIT socket lingering

Tags: apache-2.2

I've troubleshooted the heck out of this today, and I can't seem to find any information on how to determine what is happening exactly.

Basically, on my development server, another developer is causing CLOSE_WAIT connections that eat up one or more apache2 processes for several hours if I don't restart apache2.

- strace on any of the processes yields no information, only that it was able to attach.
- mod_proxy is not enabled.
- KeepAlive is on, KeepAliveTimeout is 15 seconds, MaxKeepAliveRequests is 100.

---

From what I've been reading, this may or may not be an apache issue at all, just that that's how CLOSE_WAIT works (the server is waiting for a FIN packet to close the connection).

I just can't believe that a server would be crippled so easily by not receiving a packet from a remote host telling it to close the connection. Especially without any intervention for well over an hour.

Any tips? I'm about to pull my hair out.

---

**Edit :**  Also, there are no unusual entries in any apache log files.

---

**Edit 2:** lsof -i shows only a single CLOSE_WAIT per hanging process. (That's what has been bothering me about this, as most other discussions talk about many CLOSE_WAIT connections, while I only have one per process.)

The nature of the code that is running (php) doesn't really lend itself to closing open connections and whatnot. I can run the same code that he is executing with the same session data, and not result in a hanging process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up mod-status, and in the config (debian /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf) set your IP in Allow from, and set

```
ExtendedStatus On
```

Then visit your server's default host website, and append /server-status/ to the end of the URL. That should give you more information on what the server is up to.

Sorry that this isn't really a fix, but more a way to get more information! I wasn't able to just comment on your question.

Comment: Thanks much for this! At least now I can see what page is being executed and rule out any code problems.

Comment: By the way : If you're trying to set up mod_status and you have many VirtualHosts in your config, you need to use a different port to call /server-status as the VirtualHost gets called before mod_status can be used.

Answer (score 0):

See [Running lsof -i shows a lot of connections in CLOSE_WAIT ? Should I worry](https://serverfault.com/questions/65944/running-lsof-i-shows-a-lot-of-connections-in-close-wait-should-i-worry) and for similar discussion. Probably your developer doesn't close properly the connection. CLOSE_WAIT should time-out in normal circumstances, something is preventing it.

You could try a roll-back to application version that didn't have this bug and see what changed in-between.

Comment: lsof -i shows only a single CLOSE_WAIT per hanging process. (That's what has been bothering me about this, as most other discussions talk about many CLOSE_WAIT connections, while I only have one per process.)

The nature of the code that is running (php) doesn't really lend itself to closing open connections and whatnot. I can run the same code that he is executing with the same session data, and not result in a hanging process.